# Help with the indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{2x^4 + 3x^2 + 5}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

I start by rewriting the denominator, $2x^4+3x^2+5$, as a squared term plus a constant. To do this, we notice that the first two terms already have a common factor of $2x^2$. We can complete the square by taking half of the coefficient of our $x^2$ term, squaring it, and adding it to both the numerator and denominator.

Since the coefficient of our $x^2$ term is $3$, half of it would be $\frac{3}{2}$, and squaring it gives us $\frac{4}{9}$. So we add $\frac{4}{9}$ to both the numerator and denominator.

I started like that but I couldn't go further. Can you please help me to solve it.

Comment: This process is called [Completing the Square](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Completing_the_square#Non-monic_case) and requires special care when the leading coefficient is not $1$. There are many resources with examples and practice problems at the tips of your fingers when you search this phrase.

Comment: Attempting to factor the quartic by completing the square leads to: $ax^{4}+bx^{2}+c=\frac{\left(2ax^{2}+b\right)^{2}-\left(b^{2}-4ac\right)}{4a}=\frac{\left(2ax^{2}+b-\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}\right)\left(2ax^{2}+b+\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}\right)}{4a}$. You can see from the square roots that this strategy runs into problems when $b^{2}-4ac<0$, like the quartic in your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Substitute $t=\sqrt[4]{\frac25}x$, along with $a_{\pm}= \sqrt{ 2\pm\frac3{\sqrt{10}}}$
\begin{align}
&\int\frac1{2x^4+3x^2+5}dx
 = \frac1{\sqrt[4]{250}}\int\frac1{t^4+\frac3{\sqrt{10}} t^2 +1}dt\\
=&\ \frac1{2\sqrt[4]{250}}\int\frac{1+t^2}{t^4+\frac3{\sqrt{10}} t^2 +1}
 + \frac{1-t^2}{t^4+\frac3{\sqrt{10}} t^2 +1}\ dt\\
   =&\ \frac1{2\sqrt[4]{250}}\int\frac{d(t-\frac1t)}{(t-\frac1t)^2+a_+^2}
 -\frac{d(t+\frac1t)}{(t+\frac1t)^2-a_-^2}\\
  =&\ \frac1{2\sqrt[4]{250}} \bigg(
\frac1{a_+}\tan^{-1}\frac{t-\frac1t}{a_+} 
+ \frac1{a_-}\coth^{-1}\frac{t+\frac1t}{a_-}\bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: It is tempting, when faced with a quartic that has no odd powers, to make the substitution $u=x^{2}$, but the absence of the derivative ($2x$) in the integrand means this will likely go nowhere.

Answer (score 8):

*Another solution*

Write
$$2 x^4+3 x^2+5=2(x^2-a)(x^2-b)$$ with
$$a=-\frac{1}{4} \left(3+i \sqrt{31}\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=-\frac{1}{4} \left(3-i \sqrt{31}\right) $$ Use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1 {2 x^4+3 x^2+5}=\frac{1}{2 (a-b)}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-a}-\frac{1}{x^2-b} \right)$$
So, two simple integrals

Comment: I admit it's correct, but $\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+1}}$ is known to be $\arctan(x) + C$, but you write this as $\int{\frac{dx}{x^2-i^2}}$, you write this as a sum of partial fractions and go on like this. This is obviously correct, but in the process of calculating integrals, the usage of typical complex numbers normally is avoided.

Comment: @Dominique. Thé question is thé définition of *normally* . Cheers